# TypeError: object is not a function node.js I can,t seem to get where Im doing it wrong

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("serverConfig.json"));
var port = config.port;
var host = config.host;
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
```

> I am trying Node.js what I want to achieve is to print out the link referring to twitter where one can follow the two users if they entered the correct users id in the url bar

```
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("hello");
});
app.get('/hello/:text', function(request, responce){
    responce.send("Hello " + request.params.text);
});
//user objects with user ID 1 and 2
var users = {
   "1" : {
       "name": "Lindo",
       "twitter": "lynndor_D"
   },
   "2" : {
       "name": "Xolani",
       "twitter": "mcxolani"
   }
};

app.get('/user/:id', function(request, responce){
    var user = users[request.params.id];
    if(user){
        responce("Hello" + user.name);
        responce("<a href= http://twitter.com" +user.twitter +"'>follow" + user.name + "on twitter</a>");
    }else{
        responce("Sorry! user not found", 404);// 404 is an http status code for "page not found"
    }
});
```

app.listen(port, host);

```
   enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `responce` as a function and it is an object. You need to call the method `.send` to send response to the user.

Something like this:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(request, responce){
    var user = users[request.params.id];
    if(user){
        responce.write("Hello" + user.name);
        responce.write("<a href= http://twitter.com" +user.twitter +"'>follow" + user.name + "on twitter</a>");
        responce.end();
    }else{
        responce.end("Sorry! user not found", 404);// 404 is an http status code for "page not found"
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the first one should be `responce.write()`, because `.send()` finishes the request, i think...

Comment: Ye that's it. Fixed it. Thank you